# Converting html to pdf with Arabic

Tags: php, pdf

I need to generate a pdf file with php from html, I ve use html2pdf but it doesn't support Arabic. I need something that's easy to use.

and thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try with [**TCPDF**](http://www.tcpdf.org/), I've use it in the past and got the job done, one of its listed features is:

- UTF-8 Unicode and Right-To-Left languages

So I suppose that covers Arabic.

**UPDATE**:
Yes they support it, even have an online example:

Persian and Arabic language on RTL document: [PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.pdf) and its [PHP source](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps)

Comment: in html2pdf.fr they say that it supports UTF-8 but I get question marks instead of text

Comment: but from what i see on their website it doesn't convert from html to pdf is there a plugin for that

Comment: what does it make you think so? TCPDF *only* converts from html to PDF.. see the example I put on my answer.

Comment: oh sorry didn't read the code carefully thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think you get question mark because you're not using a font that has the arabic character set. Try the almohanad font ... that's supplied with the fonts set in tcpdf under html2pdf

Answer (score 5):

the following is an example works with Arabic.

```
 <?php

include("MPDF57/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8'); 

$html = '
<p> قال الرئيس الامريكي جورج بوش في حديث متلفز في الذكرى الرابعة للغزو الامريكي للعراق ان الاولوية حاليا لاعادة الامن للعراق.</p>
<p> هل ستسفر الجهود الدبلوماسية الجارية عن حلول؟ وكيف تنظر للاتهامات لبعض هذه الدول بالتدخل في الشأن العراقي، والتورط في دعم عمليات العنف؟ والى اي مدى يبدو الوضع في العراق انعكاسا للصراعات الإقليمية في المنطقة؟</p>
<p> وادان البيت الابيض "بشدة" تفجير ايلات فيما اعربت وزارة الخارجية الروسية عن "ادانتها الشديدة" للحادث" واصفة اياه بـ"المتطرف" الذي استهدف "مدنيين مسالمين".</p>

test
';

 $html = iconv("windows-1256","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
$mpdf=new mPDF('ar','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 
// From mPDF 5.1 onwards you must set:
$mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = true;
//$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
//$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);  // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Please give me the mpdf.php

Comment: mpdf library is perfect for Arabic I recommended this lib

Answer (score 2):

Try [mPDF](http://mpdf1.com) it is very easy to use and it amazingly supports RTL languages like Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi/Persian, Urdu and Pashto. [Check the manual](https://mpdf.github.io).

Comment: I can confirm that mPDF has better support for Arabic specially when you have sentences with Arabic mixed with English. thank you for sharing.

Comment: the example link is dead. Please try to resolve the problem and relink if possible